# I am getting error on "If(rs.next())" and ".getString"

Tags: java, if-statement

I am getting error in if(rs.next()) and .getString on my code. This is my code

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       Function f = new Function();
Result rs = null;
String ans = "Key";

rs = f.find(jTextField1.getText());
try{
    if(rs.next()){
        jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString("Key"));

    }         
   }catch(Exception ex){

   }
}
```

Comment: Then that means the `Result` class does not have a method named `next` or `getString`.

Comment: Are you trying to use java.sql ? Then it is a ResultSet and that includes the next() method and a getString method.

Comment: yes im using java.sql

Comment: @rmertins yes you are exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the methods next() and getString() are parts of the java.sql.ResultSet interface. Your code should look like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    Function f = new Function();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String ans = "Key";

    rs = f.find(jTextField1.getText());
    try{
        if(rs.next()){
            jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString("Key"));
        }         
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

And  if the Function objects method find(String search) returns a valid java.sql.ResultSet implementation, you can use next() to move pointer to next Result and to check if it has one. And then you can easyly use getString(String columnName) to get the value of a column as String.

I would return ResultSet in an method like this. Let your Function class method find directly return your desired value or null or empty string. Handling the ResultSet here isn't good practice. Keep your concerns together.

Comment: i dont get it. it looks like my previous code. what should i do to remove the error?

Comment: Use ResultSet!!!!! I think your real problem is in Function class. Is this realy the name of this class?